# ShapeableImageView - Changing height results in cut-off corners when applying new ShapeAppearanceModel

Tags: android, material-ui, material-components-android, material-components, shapeableimageview

My app needs to support multiple corner radius/aspect ratio combination presets which may be displayed in different orders depending on the user profile being displayed. For example, preset A has corner radii of 42dp, 42dp, 120dp, 0dp and an aspect ratio of 1:1.5, whereas preset B has a corner radius of 60dp for all corners and an aspect ratio of 1:1.2.

I am using `ShapeableImageView`s and setting the corner radius like so:

```
shapeAppearanceModel = shapeAppearanceModel
                .toBuilder()
                .setTopLeftCorner(CornerFamily.ROUNDED, context.dpToPx(topLeft.roundToInt()).toFloat())
                .setTopRightCorner(CornerFamily.ROUNDED, context.dpToPx(topRight.roundToInt()).toFloat())
                .setBottomRightCorner(CornerFamily.ROUNDED, context.dpToPx(bottomRight.roundToInt()).toFloat())
                .setBottomLeftCorner(CornerFamily.ROUNDED, context.dpToPx(bottomLeft.roundToInt()).toFloat())
                .build()
```

I have tried setting the views' constraint dimension ratios like so:

```
(parent as? ConstraintLayout)?.let {
                val constraintSet = ConstraintSet()
                constraintSet.clone(it)
                constraintSet.setDimensionRatio(id, "1:$ratio")
                constraintSet.applyTo(it)
            }
```

and also setting the height of the views directly like so:

```
val params = layoutParams as ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams
params.height = (ratio * screenWidth).roundToInt()
layoutParams = params
```

The result is that when both the `ShapeAppearanceModel` *and* `ConstraintDimensionRatio`/height of the `ShapeableImageView` are changed, some of the corners are cut off and/or the view is otherwise distorted or displayed incorrectly.

The views always display correctly on first launch no matter the corner radii or height/dimension ratio, only after changing these attributes on the same view does the bug occur.
Changing only the corner radii without changing the height/dimension ratio works perfectly fine. I have tried calling `invalidate()` on the views before changing the height and have tried changing these attributes in different orders to no avail. Can anyone help me here? Thanks

Comment: Why do you change the constraint set of the `ConstraintLayout`? I thought you needed to change the ratio constraint of the `ShapeableImageView` instead.

Comment: @TamHuynh copied from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55911285/10257613)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just had to use `android:scaleType="centerCrop"`.